# jQuery reaction to slider change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have table data HTML element I want to reflect whatever value a slider has.

```
<td id="firstBox"></td>
<td>
    <div class="sliderHolder">
        <input type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1" id="first">
    </div>
</td>
```

Now, when I used normal JavaScript code, I could change the value of the #firstBox

```
firstSlider.oninput = function(){
    document.getElementById("firstBox").innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

But when I tried to use jQuery, I couldn't do anything (not even put a simple static int or string value)

```
firstSlider.oninput = function(){
    $("#firstBox").val(this.value);
}
```

ps.: even giving the HTML elements a name attribute haven't helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`td` elements don't have a value. Use `text()` instead.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#first').on('input', function() {
    $("#firstBox").text(this.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="firstBox">5</td>
    <td>
      <div class="sliderHolder">
        <input type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1" id="first" value="5" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

The jQuery equivalent of `.innerHTML` is the [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) method. Right now you are adding `this.value` to the `value` attribute of the `#firstBox` element.

So try this instead.

```
firstSlider.oninput = function(){
    $("#firstBox").html(this.value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In first example (vanilla JavaScript) you are directly setting innerHTML of #firstBox, whilist in second example you are setting #firstBox value. This is not right as firstBox is not an input so it doesn't really have a value.

To set it's inner html using jQuery you should do something like this

```
$('#firstBox').html(this.value);
```

Answer (score -1):

The HTML5  does only handle one value between min and max attribute. If you want to have the slide handle a min and a max value in one UI-input you could possibly use jQueryUI's slider: https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

```js
var value = $("input[type=range]").val();
$('#val').html(value)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="7" step="1" id="first">

<p id="val"></p>
```